# Redundant inheritance?

Tags: c#, inheritance

Consider that classes

```
public class Category { }
public class Product { }

public interface IService<T> { }
public class ServiceBase<T> : IService<T> { }

public class CategoryService : ServiceBase<Category> { }
public class ProductService : ServiceBase<Product>, IService<Product> { }
```

Is inheritances of ProductService redundant? Just `ServiceBase<Product>` is enough?

I just made tests like this

```
static void Main(string[] args) {
    Console.WriteLine("CategoryService interfaces:");
    foreach(var item in typeof(CategoryService).GetInterfaces()) {
        Console.WriteLine(item.Name);
    }

    Console.WriteLine("ProductService interfaces:");
    foreach(var item in typeof(ProductService).GetInterfaces()) {
        Console.WriteLine(item.Name);
    }

    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

**output**

```
CategoryService interfaces:
IService`1
ProductService interfaces:
IService`1
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes it's redundant.

You can remove it and `ProductService` will still implement `IService<Product>`

Answer (score 2):

Yes, inheriting from `ServiceBase<Product>` is enough.
But the easiest way to check is to see if your derived class also contains methods/properties defined by the interface (via IntelliSense).

Comment: The intellisense trick is not safe, because you can also have the same methods defined without implementing the interface

Comment: @digEmAll, but wouldn't you get an error/warning telling you that you have a duplicate method and you should use the 'new' keyword if you intended to override it, or something like that... you know what I'm talking about.  In any case, if you actually want to check/test to get the answer to the question, then don't put another method with the same definition in your derived class.  :)

Comment: No, I didn't meant that... What I was trying to said is (hoping my poor english will be enough to clarify...): if you have class `A` inheriting from class `B`, and `B` does NOT implement interface `IB`, but has the same methods of `IB`, you can't know if `B` (and conseguently `A`) implements `IB` or not, just using the intellisense... you definitely need a "Go to definition" click :)

Comment: Well, yes, true.  So don't do that if all you're trying to do is get an answer to your question.  :)

Answer (score 2):

It all depends on ***why***...

By itself it adds nothing, except perhaps a name. It might be useful if you have a serializer that doesn't like generics (unless wrapped), or if you want to add/override methods/attributes, or if you simply want a fixed name.

Note also that extension methods can be used to add(-ish) methods to such types (without inheritance), and that a using-alias can be used to name it **in a single file**.

Personally I wouldn't subclass it unless I had a reason.

Comment: I don't see how any of this answers the redundancy question.

Answer (score 1):

There's a case when re-implementing IFoo in the derived class is not redundant: it's if the IFoo interface was implemented explicitly in the base class and you want to override the implementation.
Look at this example:

```
interface IFoo
{
    void Foo();
}

class BaseFoo : IFoo
{
    void IFoo.Foo()    {
        Console.WriteLine("foo");
    }
}

// you can't ovverride the Foo() method without re-implementing the interface
class DerivedFoo : BaseFoo, IFoo 
{
    void IFoo.Foo()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("derived foo");
    }
}

class Example 
{

   static void Main() 
   {
        BaseFoo bf = new BaseFoo();
        ((IFoo)bf).Foo();

        bf = new DerivedFoo();
        ((IFoo)bf).Foo();

   }          
}
```